# Which Java Framework is best for large DML operation

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

My Java project use high Insert, Update and Delete operation(around 50 update operation per second but no select operation). Currently I am using SQL Server+Java+JDBC+Apache ActiveMQ. I want to re-factor my Project to fast database operation. What framework should I use like Hibernate or simple JDBC.

Comment: 50 a second is not 'very high'; high maybe.

Comment: Have you considered writing to memory and just occasionally flushing to disk in large batches? If you have no worries about losing data if the database goes down then this will likely be optimal and nosql databases such as Redis are perfect for this

Comment: i could not use nosql. Because my one java project is updating database and two web application is accessing it. If i use nosql then work will be around 1 year and client will not allow it

Comment: for 50 update operation per second any framework like hibernate/spring-jdbc will work, if you are using properly. :)

Comment: some performance issue. It is a train timing application and performance matter a lot. I need best solution. Will hibernate framework will do any benefit over JDBC?

Comment: Few questions 1) Have you profiled your app for the slowness in the first place 2) Any modern database/framework can handle more than a 1000(probably even more)with ease 3)What exactly are these queries doing? Are they I/O intensive ?. Just by swapping out frameworks wont do any benefit at all.

Comment: Hibernate adds ORM above JDBC. It will help application designer to easily maintain business relations between objects ... for a cost in performance ! When using hibernate it is common to have to use plain JDBC on some time critical operations (after identifying they **are** the bottleneck). So Hibernate will not give you any benefit in you use case.

Comment: Dear Madusudanan, I profiled my application and it is fine. Performance issue is on DB server(DB System). It also have high configuration 16 GB RAM. database is SQL server 2008 r2. They are updating two table. one train journey and journey detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should google for batch.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

Your 50 operations per second is not very high, any hibernate can manage it. But if you are interested in performing hundreds operations per second, you need to create a batch. In batch you are aggregating many operations into one instruction.
In a nutshell:
use save method for lets say 200 operations, then run flush(commit)

If you want to be more light, but write some code, plain JDBC can do it, you simply must disable autocommit.
Example below:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- optimize your database commands
- create batches, so multiple inserts, multiple updates, multiple deletes are executed at once
- check your database design: indexes optimizes read commands but slows down write commands
- ponder whether you need a small table used as middle-point, storing scheduled commands: whenever a new command is needed, you store it as a schedule command and periodically you execute the scheduled commands and remove executed commands from your table